# Give an example of a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous except at the integers

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I need an example please. I am not sure how to provide an example

Comment: $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$

Comment: $f(x) = \chi_{\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}}$

Comment: As you may have realized from the various suggested examples, the idea is to start with a picture of a nice continuous function in your head and then make it jump at every integer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An indicator function for integers $I_\mathbb{Z}(x)$:

$f(x)=1$ when $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ i.e. $x$ is an integer

$f(x)=0$ when $x \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ i.e. $x$ is not an integer